# Using SpringBootData, MySql 5.7 and query spatial

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to search all the points near a given point using a jpa query:

```
     public List<Locale> findByPosizioneNear(Point p, Distance d);
```

Here there is my Entity "Locale"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locale", catalog = "tandemblind")
public class Locale implements java.io.Serializable {
private Long              id;
private String            nome;
private Point             posizione;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name = "POSIZIONE", columnDefinition = "Point", nullable = false)
public Point getPosizione() {
    return this.posizione;
}
//other getter and setter
```

I know that with jpa is possible to use
the keyword **near** [spring data repository query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

I'm using Springboot v2.0.0.M5 and hibernate 5.2.6.Final

When I try to use the repository, I'm getting this error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create query metamodel for method public abstract java.util.List com.tandem.backend.model.repository.EventoRepository.findByLocalePosizioneNear(org.springframework.data.geo.Point,org.springframework.data.geo.Distance)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:108) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:215) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$null$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:525) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$2(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:527) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:518) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:315) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported keyword NEAR (1): [IsNear, Near]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:318) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:137) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:262) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:105) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:215) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$null$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:525) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$2(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:527) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:518) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:315) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
```

I already set in the application.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
```

I don't understand what is the issue here. Could be that MySql 5.7 doesn't support this query?

Any body please help.

Best Regards
Angelo

Comment: Spring has the problem with the function name. It isn't getting anywhere near a database. Just look at the trace!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of achieving the same calculation in a different way. First extends your repo from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

```
interface Repo extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<...>
```

Let's say we want to find all rectangles with area between given two numbers.

```
Iterable<Rectangle> getWhereAreaBetween(double from, double to){
   return repo.findAll(Specifications.where((root, query, cb) -> {
       return cb.between(cb.prod(root.get("height"), root.get("width")), from, to);
   })
}
```

I hope similar approach can be applied in your case to fill the lack of `Near` query keyword.