# How would I use NEAR with MySQL and JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-8.0

It seems that NEAR is not supported:

I get this error:

> Unsupported keyword NEAR (1): [IsNear, Near]

This is my repository:

```
public interface GeoTestRepository extends JpaRepository<GeoTest, String> {
    GeoResults<GeoTest> findByLocationNear(Point p, Distance d);
}
```

As for MySql:

```
SELECT VERSION();
8.0.11
```

Connector's dependency is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Entity is:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Arrays;
@Entity
public class GeoTest {

    @Id
    private String id; // SET/GET
    private GeoJsonPoint location; // SET/GET
}
```

Below is the Exact exception that I am getting.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'geoTestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'geoTestRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoTestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.geo.GeoResults com.example.demo.repository.GeoTestRepository.findByLocationNear(org.springframework.data.geo.Point,org.springframework.data.geo.Distance)! Unsupported keyword NEAR (1): [IsNear, Near]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoTestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.geo.GeoResults com.example.demo.repository.GeoTestRepository.findByLocationNear(org.springframework.data.geo.Point,org.springframework.data.geo.Distance)! Unsupported keyword NEAR (1): [IsNear, Near]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.geo.GeoResults com.example.demo.repository.GeoTestRepository.findByLocationNear(org.springframework.data.geo.Point,org.springframework.data.geo.Distance)! Unsupported keyword NEAR (1): [IsNear, Near]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported keyword NEAR (1): [IsNear, Near]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:318) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 78 common frames omitted

2018-05-21 15:47:36.276 ERROR 9512 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4218d6a3] to prepare test instance [com.example.demo.test.GeoTestTest@52ca2652]
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015444/1128918)? Also, if that solution doesn't work for you, you may consider giving more information about your setup: What Hibernate/SpringBoot version you have? What MySQL version you're using? How your method call looks like when the exception is thrown? What's the exact stack? Additionally, you may refer to the help page "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: dump of SQL log and exact exception can be helpfull to answer

Comment: I'm not sure how to do a dump of SQL log

Comment: @Noman what you did finally, i am facing the same issue, did couple of attamps for diff approches, nothings is working.

Comment: @PankajArora I decided to use mongoDB.

Comment: @Noman do you have any working example for this?

Comment: No I don't. I don't think spring boot supports this feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data JPA is based on JPA. Derived queries create a query based on the JPA Criteria API. `near` seems to be an extension to SQL by MySql. Therefore your analysis is correct: near is not supported for derived queries.

Use a `@Query` annotation with `native=true` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please try  this :

### Entity

```
@Entity
public class GeoTest {

    @Id
    private String id; // SET/GET
    @GeoIndexed 
    private Point location; // SET/GET
}
```

### Repository

```
public interface GeoTestRepository extends Repository<GeoTest, String> {
    List<GeoTest> findByLocationNear(Point p, Distance d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on MySql Query + Spring Data JPA + Rest Services. You need to pass lat/lang coordinates in the URL.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/admin/")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;



    @GetMapping("nearbyusers/{latitude}/{longitude}")
    public List<User> getNearbyUsers(@PathVariable double latitude,@PathVariable double longitude)  {
        List<User> nearbyUsers=  this.userRepository.findAllNearByUsers(latitude,longitude);


        return nearbyUsers;

    }


}


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

     @Query(value ="SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?1) ) * cos( radians(  latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?2) ) + sin(     radians(?1) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM user WHERE roles='USER' HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",nativeQuery = true)
     List<User> findAllNearByUsers(double lat,  double longi);


     User findByUsername(String username);


}
```